# Post from front-end with post types, categories and taxonomies

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-recommendation, forms

I am now developing a wordpress site that will be something like a directory. People will be able to submit walkthroughs, advanced reviews, as well as cheat codes for games. We were going to make a different form for each page, but now we've decided that one form with a drop down will be just fine.

There doesn't seem to be a good plug in out there, that I can find, which accommodates the fact that each submission needs to be pushed through as a "pending post" but also to a certain post type.

For example, the form that we'll use will be set up like this:

```
Game name: <post title>
Platform:  <Taxonomy>
Category:  <Category> (role playing, FPS, adventure, etc..)
This is a: () Review () Tutorial () Cheat list  <this is the post type>
Content: <post body>
Tags: <tags>
[Submit]
```

Upon submission, I need for the review, cheat, or tutorial to be set as a pending post, in the post type chosen from the radio boxes.

I'm currently using WP User Front End, but I could probably use any post from front-end form that is suggested for easiest modification. Adding the new fields to the form is easy, making them do stuff is hard! I'd appreciate any help I can get with this, our website sort of revolves around these feature.

Comment: Also, purchasing software isn't an issue as long as the price is right. We bought Formidable forms because they boast a rich text editor, but I could not find a setting that set submissions as pending posts, let alone with a Post Type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Gravity Forms](http://gravityforms.com) can do this. I just did a quick search on the support forums and found this, an answer to someone asking almost exactly the same question as you:

> Gravity Forms can be used to create
>   custom post types as well as custom
>   taxonomies, however it doesn't do so
>   out of the box. It requires the use of
>   available hooks to tell Gravity Forms
>   to use a custom post type or custom
>   taxonomy instead of the default. By
>   default it uses standard WordPress
>   Posts, Categories and Tags.
>
> So yes it is possible, but it does
>   take some custom code. When you are
>   ready to implement this you can search
>   the forums for code examples as many
>   people have done this, or you can post
>   a new post describing what you are
>   trying to do and request some
>   assistance and we can assist you with
>   basic code snippets to get you
>   started.
>
> We do plan on creating an Add-On in
>   the future that will make it much
>   easier to create custom post types and
>   use custom taxonomies.

Comment: Thank you! We got a formidable refund and purchased gravity forms! Hope this works!

Answer (score 5):

there are some free plugins that let you submit posts from frontend:

- [TDO mini forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/)
- [Post From Site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-from-site/)
- [One Quick Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-quick-post/)

and a better paid one would be:

- [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/)

But none of them will give you the flexibility as a custom coding to your needs,
and really a post from front end is a matter of displaying a form and processing it ,so following your use case your form would be something like this:

```
<!-- New game Post Form -->
<div id="postbox">
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="">

<!-- game name -->
<p><label for="title">Game name</label><br />
<input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
</p>

<!-- game platform assuming that the taxonomy is named platform -->
<p><label for="Platform">Platform:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Platform&tab_index=4&taxonomy=platform' ); ?></p>

<!-- game Category -->
<p><label for="Category">Category:</label><br />
<p><?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'show_option_none=Category&tab_index=4&taxonomy=category' ); ?></p>

<!-- game post type assuming that the post types are named: review,tutorial,cheat_list-->
<p><label for="post_type">This is a:</label><br />
<p><select name="post_type" id="post_type">
    <option value="review">Review</option>
    <option value="tutorial">Tutorial</option>
    <option value="cheat_list"> Cheat list</option>
</select></p>

<!-- game Content -->
<p><label for="description">Content</label><br />
<textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
</p>

<!-- game tags -->
<p><label for="post_tags">Tags:</label>
<input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
<p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_game_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
</form>
</div>
```

and your form processing would be:

```
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_game_post") {

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
    if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
        $title =  $_POST['title'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter a game  title';
    }
    if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
        $description = $_POST['description'];
    } else {
        echo 'Please enter the content';
    }
    $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_category' => array($_POST['cat']),  // Usable for custom taxonomies too
        'tags_input'    => array($tags),
        'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
        'post_type' => $_POST['post_type']  // Use a custom post type if you want to
    );
    //save the new post
    $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post); 
    //insert taxonomies
    wp_set_post_terms($pid,array($_POST['Platform']),'platform',true);
}
```

its not perfect but its a start and you should get the idea.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! Yet again! My husband has started to call you my boyfriend because you always answer my questions with extraordinary detail and accuracy :p

Comment: Also I like the name change... easier! I'll give this a try. We did buy gravity forms and I found some plugins that might do the trick. Now I feel like I've got a great start. WP stack rocks.

Comment: hamm, I don't know how to reply to that... i guess you just happen to ask good questions when my muse for answering is full on. LOL